# How to deal with emotion like \ud83 in twitter by regular expression in R

Tags: regex, r, twitter

I am retrieving data from twitter. The problem is that some tweets will contain emotions such as \ud83. When I apply function to calculate the twitter sentiment score. I always got error when the twitter contain \ud83. How can I use regular expression to gsub it?

```
sample input:
"MarinaCbra delta mexico delta havingfun cancun happytrails \ud83d\udc9b️lifeiscrazygood ️\ud83d\udc9b httptcoOwsYWAcEE"
expected output:
"MarinaCbra delta mexico delta having fun cancun happy trails life is crazy good ️ httptcoOwsYWAcEE"
Updated: no '\' and split some combined words. For example, havingfun to having fun.

error message:
Error in tolower(sentence) : 
invalid input 'RT DaniCim YO Delta I PAID GOOD  FOR THIS WIFI AND IT BARELY WORKS ��������������������' in 'utf8towcs'

Code for formatting sentence:(sentence is the input value, class is string)
sentence = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', sentence)
sentence = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', sentence)
sentence = gsub('\\d+', '', sentence)
```

Comment: could you provide a sample input along with the expected output?

Comment: If you just want to get rid of the non-alpha numeric characters, try `gsub("[^[:alnum:]]","", sentence)`

Comment: @MrFlick it removes spaces as well. try `gsub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', '', sentence)`

Comment: Thank you@MrFlick and @Avinash Raj. It works as my expectation.

Comment: @MrFlick Could you help me with my updated requirement? Would it be possible to give me some online resources for regular expression? I really appreciate your help! =)

Comment: How regex would know `happy` and `trails` are two separate words?

Comment: So bad. I have no idea...the original one is #happytrails. So, I do not know whether I can figure out how to split these two words.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a simple/efficient/reliable approach for splitting words that are accidentally joined. For regex refs, try [http://www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and [`?regex`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html).

Comment: The two patterns suggested will eradicate punctuation, as well. You could use`gsub("[^[:print:]]","", sentence)`, which matches anything other than digits, letters, punctuation, and spaces.

Comment: An excellent free guide to regex is the Sanchez piece: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgastonsanchez.com%2FHandling_and_Processing_Strings_in_R.pdf&ei=9wNSVNWUOsmjgwTQ9YOwBQ&usg=AFQjCNG6I-wYccJNLu_ZKaeqbxqF8-Ez3g